# Ubuntu on Azure VM suddenly unable to connect out to the internet but can still serve incoming requests - how to monitor this?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, ubuntu-18.04

I have an Azure VM running on Ubuntu and it's a production server.

Sometime after 26th August 2022, it was unable to reach out to the internet. Even though it can still serve incoming requests.

I was wondering if there's a way for me to monitor that the server itself is unable to reach out to the internet.

I don't have an Azure admin panel for this azure VM but I can ask the customer to follow the steps where needed.

Comment: Make a tcpdump and analyze with whireshark whenyou have the issue

Comment: And https://www.linux-dev.org/2012/08/logging-packages-with-iptables-and-ulog/

Comment: Last option: ntop

Answer (score 1):

Use a service such as https://healthchecks.io/ which requires your server to perform a periodic call to the internet. If the time between calls exceeds a set interval, it will fire an alert.